# Align Label with Span on Same Line - CSS

Tags: css, html, asp.net-mvc-3

OK, I am really embarrassed that I cannot figure this out but...
I have form labels that are followed by a "required" asterisk. The asterisk simply drops to the next line under the label text instead of aligning next to the text.

I want the required asterisk to end up on the same line as the label text. I shouldn't have to use floats for this right? They are in the same div so I am not sure why they just don't lay next to each other.

Thanks!

[image]

```
    <div id="letsGetStarted">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewClub.NewClubName) <span class="required">&#42;</span></div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.NewClub.NewClubName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewClub.NewClubName)


        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClubTypes) <span class="required">&#42;</span>
        </div>

        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClubTypes, Model.ClubTypes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClubTypes)

        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn"/> <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn ltgrey" /> 
        </p>
    }
</div>
```

I have a working example of the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/castonzo/sSVPc/):

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap span into the `<label></label>`

```
<div>
    <label for="NewClub_NewClubName">Name your club <span class="required">*</span></label> 
</div>
```

you can set `margin` to move it to left according to your need:

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sSVPc/1/)

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sSVPc/2/)

**Update**

As you are using `@LabelFor()` so give this to your label:

`display:inline;`

Comment: Problem is with a LabelFor helper, you cannot inject HTML in between the label tags

Comment: Okk then give your label a style `display:inline` and it will work

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot mess with HTML, but you can with CSS>

```
label{display:inline; clear:both;}
```

be careful, because this will affect all labels...

Answer (score 2):

In plain HTML5 and CSS3, you can use the following rule.  I don't know how to translate this to ASP.net:

```
.required:after {
    content: "*";
}
```

Then, just write your HTML as

```
<div>
    <label for="NewClub_NewClubName" class="required">Name your club.</label>
    <input ...>
</div>
```

On the other hand, you can use the HTML5 `required` attribute, which I don't know how to translate to ASP.  With `placeholder`, you might not need a label.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="newClub" placeholder="New club name" required/>
</div>
```

You can style this using the pseudoclass `:required`.  If you put the label afterwards so you can use the CSS3 adjacent selector, you can even try:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="newClub" name="newClub"
        placeholder="New club name" required/>
    <label for="newClub">New club name.</label>
</div>
```

and

```
input:required + label:before {
    content: "*";
    color:   red;
}
```

But again, I don't know ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    #letsgetStarted {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #letsgetStarted label {
        float:left;
        width:auto;
    }
    #letsgetStarted span.required {
        float:left;
    }
```

Place your html text inside label tags.
I did not try it though. It should work for you.